# Test Code coverage to Cover Catch Block

Tags: code-coverage, try-catch

My Apex Class where I'm having a validation rule for duplicate name check in Catch block

```
 public pagereference save(){      
        try{
            upsert complexity;
            pg = new ApexPages.StandardController(complexity).view();     
            pg.setredirect(true);       
        }catch(exception ex){
            if(ex.getmessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION')){
                String[] errorMsg = ex.getMessage().split('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,');
                String[] errorMsgOnly = errorMsg[1].split(':');
                apexPages.addMessage(new apexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,+errorMsgOnly[0].trim()));             
            }else{
                apexPages.addMessage(new apexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'An unexpected error occurred. Please contact the support group with the error message'+ex.getmessage()));
            } 
            return null; 
        }   
        return pg;
    }
```

My Test Class to cover the catch block is something like this

```
static testMethod void productComplexity_Negative(){     
       ProductComplexity__c pc = new ProductComplexity__c(name='test',Market_Segment__c='Small',Product_Type__c='New');
       insert pc;


       try {
        ProductComplexity__c pc1 = new ProductComplexity__c(name='test',Market_Segment__c='Small',Product_Type__c='New');
           insert pc1;
           ApexPages.standardController sc = new Apexpages.StandardController(pc1);
       HBCProductComplexity hpc = new HBCProductComplexity(sc); 
           hpc.Save();         
}catch(DMLException e) {
        system.debug('all ok'+e);
        system.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: Code Covered]

But still I'm unable to cover the catch block.Since I'm inserting pc1 with the same name getting validation error their itself and it is not covering anything in the method

Comment: Instead of this hack- `ex.getmessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION')` use DMLException to catch DML relation validation message. Probably you're not able to cover the else part in your class? you should also highlight lines of code not getting covered.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: you should add asserts to verify the expected result. Maybe the records are not getting created, also check the debug logs while running the test class.

Comment: at 'insert pc1' validation rule is triggering and it is entering into catch block and hence the remaining code is not executing. How to overcome this

Comment: it should work if you remove the code `insert pc1`, as it would then try to upsert from the controller's save method.

Comment: Perfect. It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inserting the record in try block of test class, call save method `hpc.Save();` as it would execute DML inside the main class with the upsert statement, thus covering the controller's catch.